# ASP.NET Search Field Enter Button Issue

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a web page with 3 search fields on it, each with a different submit button.  When using the enter button on the keyboard to submit any of them, an incorrect action is being performed, although with the mouse it's fine.

Any ideas why this is happening?

The rendered HTML as requested below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head id="ctl00_ctl00_Head1">


<body id="home">

    <form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="history_lookup.aspx?theme=t2" id="aspnetForm">

<div>

<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />

<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />

<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwULLTE1MzkzOTQxNDBkGAEFHl9fQ29udHJvbHNSZXF1aXJlUG9zdEJhY2tLZXlfXxYFBSZjdGwwMCRjdGwwMCRNaW5pQ2FydFRleHQxJEltYWdlQnV0dG9uMQUsY3RsMDAkY3RsMDAkVG9wTmF2JFF1aWNrU2VhcmNoMSRJbWFnZUJ1dHRvbjIFLGN0bDAwJGN0bDAwJFRvcE5hdiRRdWlja1NlYXJjaDEkSW1hZ2VCdXR0b24xBShjdGwwMCRjdGwwMCRjcGhSb290JGNwaFN1Yk1hc3RlciRzdWJtaXQxBShjdGwwMCRjdGwwMCRjcGhSb290JGNwaFN1Yk1hc3RlciRzdWJtaXQy4UTdoX+Ej1GFsXGOrI898SMftDA=" />

</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

//<![CDATA[

var theForm = document.forms['aspnetForm'];

if (!theForm) {

    theForm = document.aspnetForm;

}

function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {

    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {

        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;

        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;

        theForm.submit();

    }

}

//]]>

</script>





<script src="/WebResource.axd?d=gfGwAOwAxcQ9Nlq6l3EJfg2&amp;t=634166396192656250" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div>

    <input type="hidden" name="__PREVIOUSPAGE" id="__PREVIOUSPAGE" value="fwZ-2v_x8CYGGr9a8Ce0s6gkE38QmubHNljKJaKxZV41" />

    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWCAKs3Nu8DwLV2a2zBwKK/6PwCQLBpvyBBAKT+aizBgL+qMTTDwLU1/SWCwL+qNiuCArtGFkuC9Zj3X3If1cwPC7PKtcm" />

</div>

        <div class="container clearfix" style="left: 0px; top: 0px">

            <div class="utilityNav">

        <a class="MenuItem" href="/extranet.aspx?theme=t2" title="Account Info">

            Account Info

            </a>


            &nbsp;|&nbsp;



        <a class="MenuItem" href="/history_lookup.aspx?theme=t2" title="Order History">

            Order History

            </a>


            &nbsp;|&nbsp;

        <a class="MenuItem" href="/_user_logout.aspx" title="Sign Off">

            Sign Off

            </a>

            </div>                

            <div class="header">

                <div class="cart" >

    <div id="menu">

             <div class="cartimage">

              <input type="image" name="ctl00$ctl00$MiniCartText1$ImageButton1" id="ctl00_ctl00_MiniCartText1_ImageButton1" src="images/bg-cart-corner.gif" align="left" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ctl00$MiniCartText1$ImageButton1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, &quot;&quot;, &quot;cart.aspx&quot;, false, false))" style="border-width:0px;" />

        </div>


            <div class="cartlabel">Checkout Cart:<br />

         <a id="ctl00_ctl00_MiniCartText1_lbMiniCart2" class="cartlink" href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ctl00$MiniCartText1$lbMiniCart2&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, &quot;&quot;, &quot;cart.aspx?theme=t2&quot;, false, true))">View your cart</a>

        </div>


        <br /><br />

    </div>

                </div>

            </div>



<div class="primaryNav">



        <div class="navdropdown">

              </div>

         <div align="right" class="quicksearch">

<div class="QuickSearch">

    <div id="ctl00_ctl00_TopNav_QuickSearch1_quicksearchpanel" onkeypress="javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, 'ctl00_ctl00_TopNav_QuickSearch1_ImageButton1')">


        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="QuickSearch">

            <tr>

                <td class="quicksearch_text">

                    <span id="ctl00_ctl00_TopNav_QuickSearch1_lblSearch"></span>

                </td>

                <td >

                    <input class="QuickSearch" type="text" name="searchstring" size="15" maxlength="30" value="Search" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Search') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Search';}"  />

                </td>

                <td class="quicksearch_button">



                                <input type="image" name="ctl00$ctl00$TopNav$QuickSearch1$ImageButton2" id="ctl00_ctl00_TopNav_QuickSearch1_ImageButton2" src="images/searchbutton.gif" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ctl00$TopNav$QuickSearch1$ImageButton2&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, &quot;&quot;, &quot;/Searchdh.aspx?theme=t2&quot;, false, false))" style="border-width:0px;" />


                </td>

            </tr>

        </table>

</div>

</div>

         </div>

</div>

        <td valign="top">

    <div class="HistoryLookupPage">

<h1 class="PageHeader">

    <span id="ctl00_ctl00_cphRoot_cphSubMaster_PageHeader1_LabelHeader">Order History</span>

</h1>

        <p>

            Enter the reference number of the order you want to see.

        </p>

        <p>

            Reference number

            <input name="ctl00$ctl00$cphRoot$cphSubMaster$CustomerReference" type="text" id="ctl00_ctl00_cphRoot_cphSubMaster_CustomerReference" class="borderTextBox" />

            <input type="image" name="ctl00$ctl00$cphRoot$cphSubMaster$submit1" id="ctl00_ctl00_cphRoot_cphSubMaster_submit1" src="images/buttons/findorder-blue.gif" style="border-width:0px;" />

        </p>

                <br />

                <p><b>Or search by PO Number</b></p>



                <p>



            <input name="ctl00$ctl00$cphRoot$cphSubMaster$CustomerReference2" type="text" id="ctl00_ctl00_cphRoot_cphSubMaster_CustomerReference2" class="borderTextBox" />

            <input type="image" name="ctl00$ctl00$cphRoot$cphSubMaster$submit2" id="ctl00_ctl00_cphRoot_cphSubMaster_submit2" src="images/buttons/findorder-blue.gif" style="border-width:0px;" />

        </p>        

    </div>

        </td>

        </tr>

        </table>

        </div>

    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

and the aspx markup

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" %>

<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="history_lookup.aspx.vb"
    EnableViewState="false" Inherits="history_lookup" ValidateRequest="false" CodeFileBaseClass="Main.Page"
    MasterPageFile="~/masters/default/main.master" RuntimeMasterPageFile="ThreeColumn.master"
    CrumbName="<%$ Resources: Language, LABEL_MENU_HISTORY %>" %>


<%@ Register Src="~/controls/Message.ascx" TagName="Message" TagPrefix="uc1" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/controls/PageHeader.ascx" TagName="PageHeader" TagPrefix="uc1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphSubMaster" runat="Server">

        <td valign="top">
    <div class="HistoryLookupPage">
        <uc1:Message ID="Message1" runat="server" />
        <uc1:PageHeader ID="PageHeader1" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources: Language, LABEL_MENU_HISTORY %>"
            EnableTheming="true" />
        <p>
            <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources: Language, LABEL_PLEASE_ENTER_ORDERREF %>"></asp:Literal>
        </p>
        <p>
            <asp:Literal ID="Literal2" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources: Language, LABEL_HISTORY_LOOKUP %>"></asp:Literal>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="CustomerReference" CssClass="borderTextBox" />
<%--            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CssClass="BtnC" Text="<%$ Resources: Language, ACTION_LOOKUP %>" />
--%>            <asp:ImageButton ID="submit1" runat="server" imageurl="~/images/buttons/findorder-blue.gif" />
        </p>
                <% if Not globals.User("Anonymous") then %>
                <br />
                <p><b>Or search by PO Number</b></p>

                <p>

            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="CustomerReference2" CssClass="borderTextBox" />
<%--            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" CssClass="BtnC" Text="Find Order" />
--%>            <asp:ImageButton ID="submit2" runat="server" imageurl="~/images/buttons/findorder-blue.gif" />
        </p>

                <% end if %>
    </div>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant rendered HTML and the aspx code?

Comment: And the relevant aspx markup?

Comment: The approach by @Joe Smith is a reasonable one for your situation. A form can only have a single default button in HTML, hence the issue you are seeing (one of the problems with the leaky abstraction that is webforms).

Comment: @oded, so set each button in a separate asp panel and set a default button for each panel is the solution suggested here?

Comment: Yeah. Not pretty, but should work. One problem with webforms is that you can only have _one_ server side form on a page. This kills the _natural_ way to setup multiple search forms on an HTML page. If you don't need these to be server side, however, you can use as many client side forms as you want (but accessing the values may be more difficult).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encase each set of fields inside a asp:panel, then set the default button for each of the asp:panels to the correct button ID. The problem is its defaulting to the wrong submit button.